# What is a good way to learn EVM? Any opinions are appreciated

Tags: evm

I am thinking of using decompiler to learn how function is called from EVM. I am trying to use ERC20 bytecode and using uncompleted decompiler and track how function is called from EVM. Any ideas to learn EVM?

Comment: If you know go then you can read the implementation in go-ethereum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ethervm.io/

Here is a link to learn EVM, hope this can help you.